# How Java HashMap.size() functions works internally?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I was just solving some problems on leetcode https://leetcode.com/problems/insert-delete-getrandom-o1/submissions/ and while using the ArrayList.size() and HashMap.size() functions I observed drastic execution time increase (14 ms to 248 ms) is the overall solution, so it got me wondering how exactly HashMap calculates it's size?

**I have not defined the initial capacity for both the collections.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashMap.size()` method returns the value of the `size` member variable. If you don't have access to the full source code locally, you can find it on GitHub: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L526

```
    /**
     * Returns the number of key-value mappings in this map.
     *
     * @return the number of key-value mappings in this map
     */
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
```

The "drastic execution time increase" you saw may be because HashMap is a more complex data structure than ArrayList. That means that operations like adding or looking up values have more overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the java docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

And https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/10-things-java-developer-should-know-hashmap-chinmay-parekh -> No. 3,4